# Paypal refused to connect from Flutter web

Tags: flutter, webview, paypal, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin

I'm Loading the web URL inside the webview, all URL is working fine. But when I try to load the Paypal screen that time getting a problem. PayPal screen successfully loading when I try from the mobile device. But when I try to load the same screen from a web Browser it's shows Paypal refused to connect. I'm doing web development using flutter. Other web site loading fine. only got the issue in Paypal.

Below url i'm trying to laoding
[https://www.paypal.com/connect//flowEntry=static&client_id=AYcri***********&redirect_uri=${_redirectUrl}&scope(0)=email&scope(1)=openid&response_type=code#](https://www.paypal.com/connect//flowEntry=static&client_id=AYcri***********&redirect_uri=$%7B_redirectUrl%7D&scope(0)=email&scope(1)=openid&response_type=code#)

[image: error screen]

below is the sample that works on mobile but does not work in the web browser

```
WebView(

        javascriptMode: web.JavascriptMode.unrestricted,

        navigationDelegate: (web.NavigationRequest request) {
          // This can intercept any navigation within the WebView.

          if (request.url.startsWith(_redirectUrl)) {
            //  final startIndex = request.url.indexOf('code=');
            String tokenPath = request.url.split("code=")[1];
            if (tokenPath.contains("&scope=")) {
              token = tokenPath.split("&scope=")[0];
      }else{
        token = tokenPath;
      }
      print(token);
      Get.back(result: token);
      return web.NavigationDecision.prevent;
    }
    return web.NavigationDecision.navigate;
  },
  onWebViewCreated: (web.WebViewController webViewController) {
    webViewController = webViewController;
    webViewController.loadUrl("https://www.paypal.com/connect//flowEntry=static&client_id=AYcri***********&redirect_uri=${_redirectUrl}&scope(0)=email&scope(1)=openid&response_type=code#",);
  },
);
```

N.B I know the Web view library is not supported for Web, I used an extra plugin that helps to support the web.

[image: Webscree Console Error]

How can I solve this issue? any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

PayPal [does not support webviews](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/reference/info-security-guidelines/#secure-applications); they should not be used for either mobile or web.

Instead, for mobile: "launch the PayPal web page within the system browser or an approved browser-view mechanism such as Safari View Controller on iOS or Chrome Custom Tabs on Android."

---

(Once you have code that opens a Safari View Controller / Chrome Custom Tab that works on mobile, it's possible there exists some plugin that will emulate and open a new browser tab when the same flutter code is run from web but I can't speak to that)